# Android - loading wrong RecyclerView item data asyncronously

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a simple app that shows a list of item. Some of the item data is loaded in another thread, but when i scroll fast it shows the wrong data.

Here is the code for the adapter:

```
package com.lorenzorapetti.pokedex.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.lorenzorapetti.pokedex.R;
import com.lorenzorapetti.pokedex.Utils;
import com.lorenzorapetti.pokedex.model.PokemonSpecies;
import com.lorenzorapetti.pokedex.model.PokemonType;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class PokemonSpeciesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PokemonSpeciesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<PokemonSpecies> mData;
    private Context context;

    public PokemonSpeciesAdapter(Context context, List<PokemonSpecies> data) {
        this.context = context;
        mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView =((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.pokemon_species_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        PokemonSpecies item = mData.get(position);
        holder.position = position;

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(Utils.getSugimoriThumbUrl(item.getIdentifier()))
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(holder.image);

        String identifier = "pokemon_species_" + Utils.convertIdentifier(item.getIdentifier())
                + "_name";
        holder.textPrimary.setText(context.getResources().getString(
                context.getResources().getIdentifier(identifier, "string", context.getPackageName())
        ));
        holder.textSecondary.setText("#" + StringUtils.leftPad(item.getId().toString(), 3, "0"));

        new AsyncLoad(item, holder, position).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData != null ? mData.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mData.get(position).getId();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.pokemon_species_image) ImageView image;
        @Bind(R.id.pokemon_species_name) TextView textPrimary;
        @Bind(R.id.pokemon_species_number) TextView textSecondary;
        @Bind(R.id.pokemon_species_primary_type)
        TextView typePrimary;
        @Bind(R.id.pokemon_species_secondary_type)
        TextView typeSecondary;
        int position;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }

    private class AsyncLoad extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, AsyncLoad.AsyncItem> {

        private WeakReference<PokemonSpecies> itemData;
        private WeakReference<ViewHolder> viewHolder;
        private int mPosition;

        public AsyncLoad(PokemonSpecies item, ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            this.itemData = new WeakReference<>(item);
            this.viewHolder = new WeakReference<>(viewHolder);
            mPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        protected AsyncLoad.AsyncItem doInBackground(Void... params) {

            List<PokemonType> pokemonTypes = itemData.get().getDefaultPokemon().getPokemonTypes();
            Log.d("App", "position: " + mPosition + ", holderPosition: " + viewHolder.get().position
                            + ", pokemon: " + itemData.get().getIdentifier() + ", size: " + pokemonTypes.size());
            String primaryIdentifier = "type_" +
                    Utils.convertIdentifier(pokemonTypes.get(0).getType().getIdentifier());
            AsyncLoad.AsyncItem asyncItem = new AsyncLoad.AsyncItem();

            asyncItem.primaryText = context.getResources().getString(
                    context.getResources().getIdentifier(primaryIdentifier + "_name", "string",
                            context.getPackageName()));

            asyncItem.primaryColor = context.getResources().getColor(
                    context.getResources().getIdentifier(primaryIdentifier, "color",
                            context.getPackageName()));

            if (pokemonTypes.size() == 2) {
                String secondaryIdentifier = "type_" +
                        Utils.convertIdentifier(pokemonTypes.get(1).getType().getIdentifier());
                asyncItem.secondaryText = context.getResources().getString(
                        context.getResources().getIdentifier(secondaryIdentifier + "_name", "string",
                                context.getPackageName()));
                asyncItem.secondaryColor = context.getResources().getColor(
                        context.getResources().getIdentifier(secondaryIdentifier, "color",
                                context.getPackageName()));
            }

            return asyncItem;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(AsyncLoad.AsyncItem asyncItem) {
            ViewHolder holder = viewHolder.get();
            if (mPosition == holder.position) {
                holder.typePrimary.setText(asyncItem.primaryText);
                holder.typePrimary.setBackgroundColor(asyncItem.primaryColor);
                if (asyncItem.secondaryText != null) {
                    holder.typeSecondary.setText(asyncItem.secondaryText);
                    holder.typeSecondary.setBackgroundColor(asyncItem.secondaryColor);
                }
            }
        }

        protected class AsyncItem {
            String primaryText;
            int primaryColor;
            String secondaryText;
            int secondaryColor;
        }
    }

}
```

What can i do to load the exact data?

Comment: so just to understand it more clear, you are setting the value of `textPrimary` and `textSecondary` in `onBindViewHolder()` where as the value of `typePrimary` and `typeSecondary` in `onPostExecute()` ? Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. Because i get the values of `typePrimary` and `typeSecondary` asyncronously from the database

Comment: and what do you mean by when you scroll faster, it shows the wrong data? Does it mean you get the right data at first and then it somehow gets you wrong data?